# ITALY: Missed the train due to wrong information provided by the seller

Tags: munich, compensation, venice, trenitalia

me and my wife are travelling from Munich to Venice. Having bought tickets directly from Trenitalia with Smart tariff (www.trenitalia.it), and seeing that the train Euro Night 463 is to depart at 23:36 from Munich central station, we arrived there at 23:00 only to discover that the train was long gone (left at 22:03)!

I checked up both the booking and the websites again and found out that trenitalia website sells tickets with wrong departure time:
[image: Trenitalia]

while the Deutsche Bahn website lists correct departure time:
[image: Deutsche Bahn]

As we have a further connection, we bought the tickets for a morning train on the spot, but now we both feel rather disappointed, not to mention the money loss due to paying late. Do we have any options to have Trenitalia reimbursing our new tickets cost? What do you suggest us to do?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: So it turned out to be Deutsche Bahn's problem, not Trenitalia's. After I contacted both of them and sent originals of the tickets to Deutsche Bahn office citing the EU regulation 1371, they finally reimbursed me the costs of the new tickets. DB said the costs of the original ticket is out of their responsibility, but rather should be resolved with Trenitalia. I don't really have a desire to pursue the matter further half a year later, but I definitely appreciate your advice!

Comment: What did Trenitalia say when you contacted them?

Comment: Just the usual "we have received your complaint and we will review it during the next 30 days".

Comment: Add what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your case should be covered by [EU passenger rights](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/rail/index_en.htm) (Regulation (EC) 1371/2007).

According to the regulation you should be able to get a refund of 50% of the original ticket price. Additionally they should refund the ticket for the new train (but you should have asked Deutsche Bahn employees in Munich on that day whether they would unlock your original ticket for the morning connection).

According to this [Trenitalia leaflet](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms-file/allegati/trenitalia/area_clienti/Brochure_Regolamento_Europeo_EN.pdf) you can submit a claim on their website.

I have no direct experience with them and therefore don't know how problematic getting a refund is in practice.

Comment: I sent an e-mail to Trenitalia the night we missed the train. I still have no response from them, however, they legally have 30 days to react. Our Italian host provided us with a refund claim paper called "Modulo Reclamo", which we unfortunately did not have enough time to submit to the Trenitalia office. I will wait for 30 days to expire and follow up with them and their supervisors if we have no luck the simple way. Thanks for assistance!